# Nginx reverse proxy is rewriting url to 127.0.0.1

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy

I have a nginx reverse proxy on a server where I run a bunch of apps, e.g. app1.domain.com, app2.domain.com, etc. I recently added a new application with the following config (with LetsEncrypt for SSL):

```
server {
    server_name app.domain.com;
    server_name_in_redirect off;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:6767;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection $http_connection;
    }


    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/app.domain.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/app.domain.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

}

server {
    if ($host = app.domain.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    }
    # managed by Certbot


    server_name app.domain.com;
    listen 80;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot


}
```

However, whenever I go to `https://app.domain.com/` it redirects to `https://127.0.0.1:6767/somelandingpage/`. What's stranger still is that if I manually fix the url to `https://app.domain.com/somelandingpage/` it loads fine, and if I click around the app to navigate to different paths it correctly stays on `app.domain.com`. This nginx config is pretty much identical to another app I use so I'm not sure why this one in particular is redirecting like this. At first I thought it was the app thinking it's URL is 127.0.0.1:6767 and redirecting there, but if I try a GET request for `https://app.domain.com/` in Postman I get `Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:6767` (which doesn't have the /somelandingpage path) so it makes me think this must be the nginx config. But if that's the case, what am I missing here?

Comment: Try adding `proxy_set_header Host $host;`

Comment: Thank you so much, that fixed it! If you post it as an answer I can mark it as correct!

Comment: Thank you, @RichardSmith - this fixed my problem too, after weeks of debugging and months of things not working.